# SQL query to calculate relation among columns of same table

Tags: sql, join

I have a table `exchange_rate` which has entries like `currA`, `currB`, `rate`. For example (don't bother about the accuracy of the rates):

```
currA       currB    rate   rowId
 USD         USD     1        1
 USD         GBP     0.87     2
 ZWD         EUR     0.5      3
 EUR         KRN     1.5      4
 RUP         USD     0.78     5
 YEN         FRA     0.67     6
 INR         RUP     1.3      7
 FRA         USD     1.08     8
 KNR         USD     0.76     9
 GBP         YEN     1.4     10
```

The rate shows the conversion rate of `currA` w.r.t. `currB`. Example: Second row indicates `1 USD = 0.87 GBP`

Now, I want the exchange rate of each currency w.r.t USD. For example, to convert EUR into USD, I can use rows 4, 9. Similarly to convert GBP to USD either can divide 1 by 0.87 (result of row 2), or I can calculate this rate from rows 10, 6 and 8.

Is there any SQL query that can help me do this?

Comment: what flavour of sql? eg sql-server-2008?

Comment: Not query-related, but wouldn't you always want to convert from Currency A directly to Currency B? The more hops between currencies you have, the more likely the last result will be imprecise due to fluctuations in rates between currencies.  Consider today:  converting 10 USD to EUR to GBP gives you 6.37382 GBP, but converting 10 USD to GBP gives you 6.374 GBP.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for taking out time on this. The answer to your question is yes I would directly want to convert A to B in case it is available like you mentioned for the example of USD to GBP. But for the example I mentioned i.e EUR to USD, there is no direct conversion available abd unfortunately I would have to jump hops. To add some more info and may be this vcan help, I need to do this in a script.so even a sub query and certain sript code can do the stuff , then that too would do good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a recursive CTE its possible to get a result but this may not work if your not using sql-server (2005 or greater).

```
declare @data table (currA varchar(3), currB varchar(3), rate decimal(4,2), rowId int)
insert into @data values
('USD', 'USD', 1, 1),
('USD', 'GBP', 0.87, 2),
('ZWD', 'EUR', 0.5, 3),
('EUR', 'KRN', 1.5, 4),
('RUP', 'USD', 0.78, 5),
('YEN', 'FRA', 0.67, 6),
('INR', 'RUP', 1.3, 7),
('FRA', 'USD', 1.08, 8),
('KRN', 'USD', 0.76, 9),
('GBP', 'YEN', 1.4, 10)

-- GBP to USD
-- EUR to USD
declare @from varchar(3) = 'GBP'
declare @to varchar(3) = 'USD'

;with cte as
(
    select
        lvl = 1,
        rt.currA,
        rt.currB,
        rt.rate,
        rt.rowId
    from @data rt
    where rt.currA = @from

    union all

    select
        lvl = t.lvl + 1,
        ct.currA,
        ct.currB,
        ct.rate,
        ct.rowId
    from @data ct
    inner join cte t on t.currB = ct.currA
    where ct.currA <> ct.currB
    and ct.currB <> @to 
)

select @from, @to, exp(sum(log(rate)))
from
(
select currA, currB, rate, rowId from cte
union all 
select currA, currB, rate, rowId 
from @data 
where currA in 
(
    select cte.currB 
    from cte 
    where lvl in 
    (
        select MAX(lvl) 
        from cte
    )
) and currB = @to
)t
```

So the result for GBP -> USD is 1.01304

Comment: Wow.. That was some sql stuff!! Will try that first thing in the morning. I will have to look for some parallel for this as I use informix sql at my workplace. Many many thanks for answering this.

Comment: Its a horrible query, probably not very efficient but seems to work for the scenarios you mentioned.

Comment: Not able to verify your answer as the system went down. However, I am still marking it as correct solution. Thanks for your help